webpack external library with externalsType as common js,, umd, , amd and module
I am bundling my own node package using webpack bundler and i need to optimize the package in order to remove library code from it.
I came across externals configuration that webpack provides to exclude from bundle via externals config.
As I have seen, they have provided lodash example and later mentioned that it should be available in consumer's enviornment and that way one does not need to bundle it along with current script and it can be excluded so small size etc...
But i am not getting what the other externalsType does here and i am not getting how and in which context those will be useful.
e.g if I keep bootstrap's dropdown library as an external from my package but then i decide not to use or depend on bootstrap global. So bootstrap is not installed on consumer's side via script tag, rather i keep it to commonjs or any other available lets say even module like this.
So webpack.config.js has something like this
 module.exports = {
    // ...
    externalsType: 'commonjs',
    externals: [
      'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown',
      'bootstrap/js/dist/tab',
      'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip',
      'bootstrap/js/dist/modal',
      'bootstrap/js/src/dom/event-handler.js',
      'bootstrap/js/src/dom/selector-engine.js',
      'bootstrap/js/src/util/index',
    ],
}

here up to this point, bundled script was fine and bootstrap dropdown was not there as expected. This is how bundled code was and marked as externals. that was great and we could have slept peacefully.
***/ "bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown":
/*!*********************************************!*\
  !*** external "bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown" ***!
  \*********************************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

"use strict";
module.exports = bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown;

/***/ }),

But then i noted that bootstrap dropdown script is anyhow coming to consumer's end where my package was being imported because externalsType is set as commonjs and only difference is that instead of import it is converted to require. That is not something i needed when i marked script as externals, instead i wanted to exclude that.
!*** ../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js ***!
  \*****************************************************/ /***/function node_modulesBootstrapJsDistDropdownJs(module,__unused_webpack_exports,__nested_webpack_require_1023153__){/*!
  * Bootstrap dropdown.js v5.3.2 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
  * Copyright 2011-2023 The Bootstrap Authors (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/graphs/contributors)
  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
  */(function(global,factory){..............whole bootstrap dropdown and not only that but popper js as well. oh no!!!

and this seems to be only prevented when externalsType is only var which is default and but then it expects on global bootstrap variable.
!*** external "bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown" ***!
  \*********************************************/ /***/function bootstrapJsDistDropdown(module){"use strict";module.exports=bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown;/***/})

and it also adds module.exports as whole string which is incorrect as well.
module.exports=bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown;

module.exports can not be bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown because that is not a variable but when considering whole bootstrap it might work because because in that case it would be just module.exports=bootstrap.
So using global concept we lack the capability of importing required parts only of library.
Also i failed at using these three scripts which i needed from bootstrap but that i can not mark externals as bootstrap does not export them entirely so they are not available under bootstrap.module syntax (e.g. bootstrap.Dropdown) even if using global concept.
'bootstrap/js/src/dom/event-handler.js',
          'bootstrap/js/src/dom/selector-engine.js',
          'bootstrap/js/src/util/index',

How would we get advantages in this case for smaller bundle using externals config? Do i have to use var only or anything else?
